# VBA Table Refreshing

Tags: vba

I'm creating a worksheet in Excel that is connected to an online database. I made a function that checks if new information has been posted and updates the worksheet accordingly. If there is a new release, I update all the column headings to make room for it using a loop.

My problem is that the function takes forever to run since the table refreshes itself each time I change the column headings.

I'm wondering is there is a way to pause the refresh so the table only refreshes itself once at the end of the vba script.

Thanks. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Is there a formula in a column that is calculating when the data is refreshed?

Comment: There is a table formula that refreshes the whole worksheet. When the loop updates the 8 column headings it refreshes 8 times rather than 1 time.

Answer (score 2):

To stop formulas from refreshing whilst the code executes, you can use `Application.Calculation` like so:

```
Public Sub SomeProcedure()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Code goes here

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

This will stop the formulas refreshing until the code in the middle has executed.